# Php isset not running

Tags: php, html

[image]

Hi guys may I ask why is my isset failed to ready parameter from the url?
The second picture is I tried to pass a id parameter into it

[image]

Comment: first of all, post code not images https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Your error is the $id is not echoed/interpreted.  change it to `echo "...alert('$id')..."` (double quotes)

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code. Code is text. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please edit your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: When you start the `href` with an `#` you reffering to an id element in the DOM not to a php script. So your PHP code will not run

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explain precisely what the code is doing instead of what you expected, but from the code we can see some likely issues:

1. Your URL looks wrong:

- A # in a URL normally tells the browser to move to an anchor in the current page, not send a request to the server
- Unless you've got some system for enabling "pretty" URLs then you'll need to put the .php extension on the end of the filename in the URL
- %s isn't a number or ID, it looks like it might be a placeholder for string replacement, but it's unclear from the code you've shown whether the text is actually inside some sort of string / command where replacement would occur.

A valid-looking example (relative) URL to put into your link might be something like `delAcc.php?id=1`, so

```
<a href="delAcc.php?id=1" class="fas fas-user-minus">
```

2. in PHP, [variables inside single-quoted strings are not interpolated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), so you'd get $id literally shown on screen in the alert.

You need to double-quote the string:

```
echo "<script>alert($id)</script>";
```